# Append a line in file with given input arguments using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, yaml

I have a YAML file with the content below:

```
job_name: "node"
scrape_interval: "15s"
static_configs:
  -  targets: ['10.10.10.11:8080']
```

now if I execute my python script it should append target line in YAML file using given arguments

```
i.e script.py -ip 10.10.20.30 -p 8181
```

file should look like this

```
job_name: "node"
scrape_interval: "15s"
static_configs:
  -  targets: ['10.10.10.11:8080', '10.10.20.30:8181']
```

for this I am using the python script below, but it's giving errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import yaml

with open('test.yaml', 'ra') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('targets:'):
            line[i] = line[i].strip() + 'arg1,arg2\n'
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems that the script doesn't do what you want. any way what are the errors that you receive? is it about indentation?

Comment: i am getting indentationError: saying expected an indented block in line 8

Comment: that's because the `with` is in the same level as `def main`, and it shouldn't be,. also you have to change the `'ra'` to `'r+'`

Comment: and another problem is with the `line[i] = line[i].strip() + 'arg1,arg2\n'` that doesn't use the function parameters but literal string, and the text you are searching for doesnt start with 'targets'. there are whute spaces abd  '-' in the beggining

Comment: aftering making above changes in script and executing, still it is not taking my input and appending to my test.yaml.
PFB my updated code again : 

#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import yaml

with open('test.yaml', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('-targets'):
            line[i] = line[i].strip() + 'arg1,arg2\n'
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)

Comment: try using`'targets:' in line[i]` instead of `startswith`

Comment: no luck after these changes

Comment: What that means "no luck"? you have errors, or the code is not working? (as I wrote, the code doesn't do what you want. you have to debug it and change it)

Comment: code is not working, need to make changes i guess

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `os`, `yaml` (i.e. PyYAML) but you are not using those packages.

You also try to "edit" the YAML file as if it is unstructured text, and you should not. Instead you should load the YAML file, then extend the data structure that you get and then dump the data structure back to the YAML file, but not with PyYAML as that doesn't support this kind of round-tripping without losing information.

Instead use [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package):

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.indent = 5
yaml.block_seq_indent = 2

ip = '10.10.20.30'  # sys.argv[2]
port = 8181         # sys.argv[4]

with open('test.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)
    targets = data['static_configs'][0]['targets']
    targets.append(type(targets[0])(str(ip) + ':' + str(port)))

with open('test.yaml', 'w') as fo:
    yaml.dump(data, fo)
```

Which will write:

```
job_name: "node"
scrape_interval: "15s"
static_configs:
  -  targets: ['10.10.10.11:8080', '10.10.20.30:8181']
```

Setting attributes `preserve_quotes`, `indent`, `block_seq_indent` is only needed to get the output to match your input. So is the copying of the type
of the first `targets` element. Actually none of the quotes in your file are needed.

If a more default YAML output file, which will load to the same data, is ok with you can do:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()

ip = '10.10.20.30'  # sys.argv[2]
port = 8181         # sys.argv[4]

with open('test.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)
    data['static_configs'][0]['targets'].append(str(ip) + ':' + str(port))

with open('test.yaml', 'w') as fo:
    yaml.dump(data, fo)
```

Please note that both the key order in multiple entry mappings, as well as any comments in your YAML file would be preserved by the above round-tripping.

You would of course still have to get the IP and port from the commandline, and concatenate the values instead of hard coding the `ip` and `port` values. I suggest using the standard python module `argparse` for that, but beware that most applications only take long options with double dashes (`--ip` instead of `-ip`)